# How to pass objects between tauri and yew front-end

Tags: rust, tauri

The Tauri docs say that a return value from a command handler can be of any type as long as it implements `serde::Serialize`.

As a very basic modification of the default `tauri` + `yew` example project I modified in my tauri application a plain `String` return type with a struct as follows:

```
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct Data {
    demo: String
}
```

so that the command becomes

```
#[tauri::command]
fn greet(name: &str) -> Data {
    Data{demo: "demo".to_owned()}
}
```

The yew front-end unfortunately seems to return `None` now where before the `msg` was successfully converted into a `String`:

```
 new_msg = invoke(
    "greet",
    to_value(&GreetArgs { name: &*name }).unwrap(),
 )
 .await;
 log(&new_msg.as_string().unwrap());
```

Comment: What is `invoke()`? How is it defined? From what I know, using Tauri from Yew+WASM requires some Javascript "glue" code, where is that? Can you provide a [minimal reproducible example](/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 2):

Is it still actual?

I'm working on my application in Tauri + Vue + TS and I think I known what kind of problem in your code.

First, you need to use invoke on frontend side from '@tauri-apps/api' package (as for Vue).
Second, you need to pass object that will contain pairs of (keys, values).

Let's look on **working** example from my code:

Backend

```rust
#[tauri::command]
#[allow(non_snake_case)]
pub async fn getPackage<'s>(packages: StatePackageIndex<'s>, id: &str) -> Result<SerdeDedutyPackage, String> {
    let package_id = id.to_string();

    for service in packages.read().await.services_ref().values() {
        if let Some(agent) =
            service.get(&package_id).await.map_err(|error| format!("Internal error: {error}"))? {
                return SerdeDedutyPackage::try_from(
                        agent
                            .read()
                            .await
                            .package_ref()
                            .to_result()
                            .map_err(|error| format!("Internal error: {error}"))?)
                    .await
                    .map_err(|error| format!("Internal error: While serialize package object: {error}"));
        }
    }

    Err(format!("Internal error: Package with uuid '{id}' not found"))
}
```

Somewhere at frontend

```js
async function refresh(totally = false) {
    if (totally)
      packages.value = []

    const updated: Set<string> = new Set(await invoke('listPackages'))

    for (const uuid of updated) {
      try {
        const serialized: IDedutyPackage = await invoke('getPackage', { id: uuid })
        if (!serialized)
          continue

        packages.value.push(DedutyPackage.fromOptions(serialized))
      }
      catch (error) {
        console.error(`Internal error: Unable to fetch Package '${uuid}' due to: ${error}`)
      }
    }
  }
```

So, to be more concrete, your frontend function must be async (or return promise) and do next:

```js
// Use JS highlight because I don't worked with Yew
const data = await invoke('greet', { name: 'grmmgrmm'})

invoke('greet', { name: 'grmmgrmm'})
  .then((data /* : Data */) => {
     console.log('Data is', data)
  })
```

More information can be found here: [Create a desktop app in Rust using Tauri and Yew](https://dev.to/stevepryde/create-a-desktop-app-in-rust-using-tauri-and-yew-2bhe)